# How is it possible to extract values from elements inside iframes using Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, selenium-ide

I am trying to validate the contents of a readonly, disabled `input` field inside an iframe using Selenium IDE 2.9.1.

Since I am running the test suites on this [HTML runner](https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java), I can only use the capabilities offered by Selenium IDE, meaning JS functions.

I tried to execute this `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('input').value` in the devtools console and it worked, but not when using `getEval` or `storeEval`.

Results of the IDE are always null, or, if I add [0] to the input, the result is `undefined`.

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the html and more of your code?

Comment: Im not an expert in Selenium IDE, whenever you want to access and element inside an iframe, you need to switch to the iframe and then search for the element. Is that something you can do with Selenium IDE?